# ReferenceError: google is not defined VUE

Tags: vuejs2

i'm using **vue2-google-map** components in **Vue** and they are workng fine.
But if i try create google object in data return or computed like

```
 new google.maps.Point(20,40)
```

have the error

> ReferenceError: google is not defined
>    at VueComponent.data (app.js:sourcemap:69896)
>    at getData (app.js:sourcemap:6550)
>    at initData (app.js:sourcemap:6509)
>    at initState (app.js:sourcemap:6440)
>    at VueComponent.Vue._init (app.js:sourcemap:7611)
>    at new VueComponent (app.js:sourcemap:7783)
>    at createComponentInstanceForVnode (app.js:sourcemap:7060)
>    at init (app.js:sourcemap:6877)
>    at createComponent (app.js:sourcemap:8532)
>    at createElm (app.js:sourcemap:8475)

Comment: That error means that the `google` object is not defined in the scope where you are accessing it. Where and how are you defining `google`? Are you using a `<script>` tag? Or are you using npm / webpack?

Comment: @thanksd, i'm using npm vue2-google-map package. he defining google api script by this expression : 
`Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: 'AIzaSyBvWE_sIwKbWkiuJQOf8gSk9qzpO96fhfY',
    libraries: 'places',
  }
})`

Comment: From the [npm README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps) it doesn't look like that sets up a global `google` variable. It looks like it provides Vue components to use in a template and adds properties to the Vue instance. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is solved!

vue2-google-map package generate Google map API script with type **async**.

so you need to wait for the full map download and then generate your components

```
<gmap-map  ref="map">
   <vue-component v-if="mapLoaded" ></vue-component>  
</gmap-map>   

<script>
        export default {      
          data () {
            return {
            mapLoaded: false,
        }
      },
            mounted:function() {
                        this.map = this.$refs.map.$mapObject;
                        this.$refs.map.$mapCreated.then(() => {
                                      this.mapLoaded=true
                    })

 </script>
```